# Run a client-side websocket app on a server-side?

Tags: websocket

I have to retrieve data periodically from a source I can only connect to through a websocket and store that data in a database.

I read about websockets and I always get to client-server scenarios, usually javascript libraries, where the client websocket is executed on the client browser.

This task should be automated and unatended. How could I develop it but server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this using [websocket-client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/) Python module that can implement javascript similar methods